# NetSuite API - How to send tracking number back to Invoice or Sales Order?

Tags: api, netsuite, updates

I'm integrating a shipping solution with NetSuite via the SOAP API. I can retrieve the shipAddress via the searchRecord call.  Now I need to send the tracking number, service used, and cost back into NetSuite.  Hoping someone can point me in the right direction as searching hasn't turned up any answers for me.  An example XML would be great.

Comment: You would need to use the `update` operation to update the fields for the record you want to change.

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: I need to build the raw XML. I'm using VBScript. This is a business requirement. VBScript is the only option.

Answer (score 0):

Im pretty much pasting what I was had an external developer attempt to implement as the response but I don't understand how to setup the envelope to receive it within NS on a record...I think this is what is handling the update post to Field:

```
'
             var a = new Array();
                                 a['Content-Type'] = 'text/xml; charset=utf-8';
                                 a['POST'] = '/FedexNSService/Service1.asmx HTTP/1.1';
                                 a['Content-Length'] = data.length;           
                                 a['SOAPAction'] = 'https://wsbeta.fedex.com:443/web-services/ship/ReturnFedexLable';
                                nlapiLogExecution('DEBUG', 'Results', 'data : ' + data);



            var response = nlapiRequestURL('http://sonatauat.adaaitsolutions.com/FedexNSService/Service1.asmx?op=ReturnFedexLable', data, a, null,null);
nlapiLogExecution('DEBUG', 'response', response);                
            var responseXML = nlapiStringToXML(response.getBody());
nlapiLogExecution('DEBUG', 'responseXML', responseXML);
                                 var responseCode = response.getCode();
nlapiLogExecution('DEBUG', 'responseCode', responseCode);
                                 var body = response.getBody();
nlapiLogExecution('DEBUG', 'body', body);                                
                                 nlapiLogExecution('DEBUG', 'responseXML '+responseXML, 'responseCode : ' + responseCode);
                                 nlapiLogExecution('DEBUG', 'body ', 'body : ' +body);
                        var imageurl ='';        
                    if(responseXML != null)
                    {

                            var rawfeeds = nlapiSelectNodes(responseXML, "//Tracking"); 
                            var FileInternalId = nlapiSelectValue(rawfeeds[0], "FileInternalId");
                            var TrackingIds = nlapiSelectValue(rawfeeds[1], "TrackingIds");
                            nlapiLogExecution('DEBUG', 'FileInternalId '+FileInternalId, 'TrackingIds : '+TrackingIds );    
                            if(FileInternalId)
                            {
                                var image=nlapiLoadFile(5985);
                                imageurl=image.getURL();
                                imageurl = ("https://system.netsuite.com"+imageurl);       
                                nlapiLogExecution('DEBUG','image',imageurl);
                            }

                    }
            return imageurl;
'
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to update a sales order with the information via SOAP you need to create a sales order object, set the values and call either an `update`, or an `upsert` method:

[JAVA]

```
SalesOrder so = new SalesOrder();
so.setExternalId("externalID"); //This should correspond to the previous external ID for updates. 
...set_other_fields_as_required...
WriteResponse wr = ns.getPort().update(so);    //ns = _port if you're using the samples
```

[C#]

```
var so = new SalesOrder();
so.externalId = "externalID";
...set_other_fields_as_required...
var wr = Service.upsert(so);
```

PHP should be similar, but I haven't used the PHP toolkit so I can't say for certain.

This should help get you started.